# How to retrieve pl/sql tables of records to Java

Tags: java, plsql

I have a RECORD Type in **pl/sql** and a table containing the above declared records

```sql
TYPE record_type IS RECORD
(a  A,
 b  B) ;
TYPE record_table IS TABLE OF record_type;
```

Note: A,B types above are custom objects in my package

Now, I want to return a cursor of the above declared table to JAVA.

When I blindly call

```sql
OPEN Cursor for 
select * from ab_record_table ;
```

It compiles, but throws following error in java when using this procedure

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete
```

Please let me know, how to handle...

Comment: if you perform select * from ab_record_table, what does resultsetsetmetadata returns as column type? Assuming you don't get any exceptions while executing the statement. or perhaps you need to take a look into CallableStatement to deal with cursors. Google returned: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/jdbc/PLSQL_and_JDBC/RefCursorExample.java

Comment: Are you open to using pipelined functions instead?

Comment: No..Looking for any other solution

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jdbc-extensions) support [oracle custom types](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jdbc/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#orcl.datatypes) like objects and arrays.